# Method for computing polar coordinates surface element?

Tags: infinitesimals, surface-integrals

I have tried to compute the "classical" surface element in polar coordinates for volume integration (i.e. $dx\ dy=r \ dr\ d\theta$) through this method:
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
x=r \cos \theta\\ 
y=r \sin\theta \\ 
\end{array}
\right. 
 =
\begin{cases}
dx=-r \sin\theta \ d\theta +dr \cos\theta \\[2ex]
 dy=r \cos\theta \ d\theta +dr \sin\theta
\end{cases}$$

And then multiply the two differential elements (and simply the $(dr)^{2}$ and $(d\theta)^{2}$ to $0$). But I always seem to end up with $dx\ dy=r(\cos(\theta)^{2}-\sin(\theta)^{2})\ dr\ d\theta$ instead of$+$ as needed to get $r\ dr\ d\theta$. Is this a problem of assumptions or algebra mistakes?

Comment: The $2\times2$ determinant formula compensates the negative sign. What exact computation are you doing ?

Answer (score 0):

When the variables are changed between $x,y$ and $u,v$, your $dx dy$ comes from the area of a rectangle, but it is mapped to a region that is not a rectangle. So instead of doing $du dv$, you will have to do $|d\vec{u}\times d\vec{v}|$, the area of a parallelogram, which gives you the jacobian. In fact, here is the formula,

$$dx dy =|\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial x}{\partial u} & \frac{\partial x}{\partial v}\\
\frac{\partial y}{\partial u} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial v}
\end{bmatrix}| du dv.$$